# Using effects package with clustered covariance matrix

Tags: r, regression, effects

I'm using R to plot interaction effects after a linear model. I'd like to plot an interaction effect with an error ribbon using the "effects" package. However, I want to calculate errors based on a multi-way clustered covariance matrix as can be calculated with the "multiwayvcov" package. "effects" can take a function to calculate a covariance matrix (vcov.=) but it looks like the function won't accept any additional arguments.

Example:

```
library(effects)
library(ggplot2)
library(multiwayvcov)
m1 <- lm(mpg ~ hp + wt + hp:wt, data=mtcars)
tmp <- as.data.frame(effect("hp:wt", model, vcov=vcov, se=TRUE, xlevels=list(wt=c(2.2,3.2,4.2))))
ggplot(data=tmp, aes(x=hp, y=fit, colour=as.factor(wt))) +
   geom_line() +
   geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper, fill=as.factor(wt)), alpha = 0.5) +
   labs(colour="wt")
```

The above produces a similar plot for the interactions using non-clustered se. I want something that does the same but with clustered se. Something like (imagine that "gear" and "cyl" are cluster ids in the mtcars data):

```
m1 <- lm(mpg ~ hp + wt + hp:wt, data=mtcars)
cluster.ids <- data.frame(i = mtcars$gear, j = mtcars$cyl)
tmp <- as.data.frame(effect("hp:wt", model, vcov=cluster.vcov(m1, cluster = cluster.ids), xlevels=list(wt=c(2.2,3.2,4.2))))
```

Comment: I don't see that this merits a downvote.